# Почему при переключении с input type="text" на input type="date" календарь не открывается?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Здравствуйте.

Так как у инпута с типом date не работает placeholder, то воспользовался хаком: изначально поле имеет тип text, а при фокусе становится date. Но проблема в том, что в мобильной версии Хрома при фокусе календарь открывается только со второго клика. То есть, как я понял, при первом клике оно меняет тип и только при втором - открывает календарь. Попробовал в UC и Safari - все ок, работает так, как мне нужно. Как можно исправить данную проблему?

Пример - http://jsfiddle.net/1t00qour/

Answer (score 1):

Стандарт запрещает менять тип инпутов. Местами такой код даже падает с исключением. <s>Зачем вообще менять тип инпута - чем не угодил вариант с date?</s>

Сделай вместо плейсхолдера лейбл с абсолютным позиционированием.

Comment: На мой взгляд, что мой, что ваш вариант - костыль. "Стандарт запрещает менять тип инпутов. Местами такой код даже падает с исключением." - можно какой-то реальный пример?

Comment: В старых IE точно исключение. Где-то писали про костыли с извлечением элемента из dom, изменением типа и возвратом обратно - не знаю, для каких браузеров.

Comment: Это совсем не критично. А решение моей задачи очень простое - нужно просто сделать .click() при изменении типа на date.

Comment: Я не проверял, где именно не работает. просто знаю точно, что старые IE так себя поведут. Возможно, кто-то ещё.